# How do I center the navigation bar within a wrapper minus the area a floated button takes up?

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div, a navigation menu bar (floated to the left) and a button (floated to the right). How do I center the navigation bar (floated to the left) within the wrapper minus the area the button (floated to the right) takes up?

So instead of it being centered directly in the middle of the wrapper, it will be centered to the the left a bit more because the area the button takes up is not within the (center) calculation; if you will. Here's a quick graphic:

[image]

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    Center Me
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    Book Now
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:not(.wrapper) {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.cta {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  background: #444;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div.nav {
  float: left;
  background: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox. Floats can be difficult and behave inconsistently. Flexbox is a great utility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

div:not(.wrapper) {
/*   display: inline-block; */
}

div.cta {
/*   float: right; */
/*   width: 100px; */
  background: #444;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

div.nav {
/*   float: left; */
  background: #777;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `float` from your `.nav` and added `width` (totalling 100%) to each container to get this result.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:not(.wrapper) {
  display: inline-block;
}

div.cta {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  background: #444;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div.nav {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    Center Me
  </div>
  <div class="cta">
    Book Now
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So that works for this example, but in the actual one the button breaks to a new line and when I change nav to display: inline-block it ruins some of the positioning I have. Thanks for sharing this though